# Movie Recommendation Model based on user behavior pattern and movie data

Tags: recommender-system

Now, I want to develop Agent Based Modeling (ABM) for movie recommendation system.

ABM is a kind of simulation system, I can set some rules for client's action.

In my current setting, I want to make client rules by using client log data.

In log data, each individuals has their own actions, coded as numeric data and likes **path**.

| customer ID | action1 | action 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X123 | 12 | 15 | ... |
| X234 | 17 | 25 | 43 |

And I also have **embedded vector** for actions.

| action | feature1 | ... | feature N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | ... | 0.561 |
| 15 | 0 | ... | 0.141 |
| 17 | 0 | ... | 0.871 |

My point is that could I combine 'my action embedding vector' and 'customer action path' for my simulation system?

I found some methodologies like Graph Neural Network, but they made embedding vector based on client log datasets.

Are there any methodologies that I can use both movie data and personal action datasets?

I considered Graph Convolution Network, but I think it is inappropriate because I want to make model deriving user's behavior path.